# Ruby Syntax: How to write "a = h[:v] if !h[:v].nil?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I find myself often writing statements equivalent to:

```
deleted_at = Time.at(data[:deleted_at]) if !data[:deleted_at].nil?
```

i'd like to be able to write this in a more concise way. Any suggestions?

Sometimes I write this as:

```
deleted_at = Time.at(i) if !(i = data[:deleted_at]).nil?
```

But I think this makes the code harder to read so I hope there is some nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use 'unless' since I find it more readable:

```
deleted_at = Time.at(data[:deleted_at]) unless data[:deleted_at].nil?
```

or you could even use:

```
deleted_at = Time.at(data[:deleted_at]) if data[:deleted_at]
```

Comment: i like using unless instead of negating if. i'll start doing that more. :)

Comment: Not bad either: deleted_at = Time.at(data[:deleted_at]) if data[:deleted_at].present?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap that generically into a lambda block:

```
class Object
  def unless_nil?
    yield self unless self.nil?
  end
end

data[:deleted_at].unless_nil? {|i| deleted_at = i }
```

I'd recommend to not monkey patch the `Object` class but better create a module and include that in the classes you need this functionality for.

Comment: interesting idea. if going down this path it think i would prefer something like: unless_nil?(data[:deleted_at]) { |i| deleted_at = Time.at( i ) } because then the "control structure" keyword is first.

Comment: Well actually it IS at the right place from OOP perspective. I'd suggest you learn to exploit ruby's extreme OOP more and write less C-ish/PHP-ish code. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
data_deleted = data[:deleted_at]
deleted_at = Time.at(data_deleted) unless data_deleted.nil?
```

makes it more readable IMO.

Comment: (unless x) is the same thing as (if !x) I would/do use this exact same syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
data[:deleted_at] and deleted_at = Time.at(data[:deleted_at])
```

although whether that's better is a matter of taste.

Comment: you'd want to use `and` instead of `&&` due to the precendence versus `=`

Answer (score 0):

Not having `deleted_at` declared like that is not my cup of tea. It would at least be set to nil with something like this:

```
deleted_at = Time.at(data[:deleted_at]) rescue nil
```

or

```
deleted_at = data[:deleted_at].nil? ? nil : Time.at(data[:deleted_at])
```

Comment: That was maybe a wanted side effect of the original implementation (not modifying it at all). I would use the (young) replacement `Time.try(:at, data[:deleted_at])` instead of the `rescue` construct.

Comment: Indeed a nice little extension by ActiveSupport. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: i like the try solution. using rescue for this i think is really bad because of performance and that using rescue for flow control is (/should be) unexpected for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the nil version evaluating to false to do this:

```
deleted_at = data[:deleted_at] and Time.at(data[:deleted_at])
```

Although now having written this i think i prefer the `if` version.

Code is written far less than its read - concise doesn't always equate to readable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only `Time.at` that's giving you problems, you could write

```
class Time
  def nil_friendly_at(time)
    return nil if time.nil? # Or "unless time"
    at(time)
  end
end
```

Or you could monkey-patch `Time.at` itself if you want (I'm not recommending this though!)

Comment: Using Time.at was just to give an example of a more general problem for me.